# What does it mean to XOR graph edges

Tags: graph, xor

This question might be a bit trivial, but what does it mean to XOR graph edges? I can't seem to find anything on Google to describe how to XOR graph edges.

Given a Bipartite graph, what happens when I XOR the edge?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some context where you heard this term? Are you asking about graph theory, or computer graphics?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard this term in relation to taking the product of two graphs. You end up taking an edge if it appears in exactly one of the two graphs. This is analogous to the Exclusive OR operation.

Look at the Alon paper: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/eyal/papers/xor4.pdf